# Callback for integer message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Folks,

i am just leanring roscpp and i want to re-write the [Simple Publisher and Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) Tutorial with an integer instead of a string. So how have i to write the callback function?

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::UInt16 msg)
{
     ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", msg->data);}
}
```

But `catkin_make` says:

```
error: ‘UInt16’ was not declared in this scope
```

Have i missed some additional headers so `std_msgs/UInt16` message isn't declared yet?

The same problem also appears also for `ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<UInt16>("test", 5);`.

Someone has a hint for me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254838/callback-for-integer-message/) by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing a header file.

For the callback, in the tutorial there is a line containing

```
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
```

You should replace that with

```
#include "std_msgs/UInt16.h"
```

For the publisher you will want to replace the line containing

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
```

with

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::UInt16>("chatter", 1000);
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on 2017-02-21**:
Oh x.x
yes, this is logical.
Thank you very much.